# Share a link to a Facebook Page using FBSDKShareAPI

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

Assuming I have all the requested permissions, I am wondering how I can allow a user to post a link to a facebook page using the FBSDKShareAPI provided by facebook. Here is how we do it for a user, but how would I do it for a page?

Login:

```
[login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile", @"email", @"user_friends"] fromViewController:self handler:nil];
```

Posting:

```
FBSDKShareLinkContent *linkContent = [[FBSDKShareLinkContent alloc] init];
// then we give the link content, then we share it
[FBSDKShareAPI shareWithContent:linkContent delegate:nil];
```

So let's say a user logs in using the same code, how then could we allow them to select a page and then post the link via the page? Here are the graph api docs, but I can't find an iOS docs for it.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/publishing

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/access-tokens
Check this link. It explains how to publish on behalf of page.

Comment: @MuhammadZohaibEhsan I saw that. But I can't figure out how to do it on iOS with their SDK

Comment: Ok Let me search a bit and I will update you  :)

Comment: see this link 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/page/feed
In this page-id is required and you can publish links etc. When /user-id/accounts is called pages and their ids and the role of user for the page is returned .Then I guess the returned page access token should be set as currentAccessToken in setCurrentAccessToken: . And make further api calls.

Comment: Just to clarify this issue; do you want to: A) post -as- a user, -to- a page, or B) post -as- a page, -to- a page?